# How can you set a select-condition on a Binding to a List?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am quite new to WPF and I'm playing around with Bindings. I manage to set a Binding to a `List` in order to display, for example, a list of people in a grid. What I would like now, is to set a condition on the Binding, and to select only people from the grid who satisfy this condition. What I have so far is:

```
// In MyGridView.xaml.cs
public class Person
{ 
    public string name;
    public bool isHungry;
}

public partial class MyGridView: UserControl
{
    List<Person> m_list;
    public List<Person> People { get {return m_list;} set { m_list = value; } }

    public MyGridView() { InitializeComponent(); }
}

// In MyGridView.xaml

<UserControl x:Class="Project.MyGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>    
         <DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I would like now, is to only include in the list `Person` instances who are hungry. I know a way to do it in code, by for example adding a new property:

```
public List<Person> HungryPeople
{
    get 
    {
        List<Person> hungryPeople = new List<Person>();
        foreach (Person person in People)
           if (person.isHungry)
                hungryPeople.Add(person);
        return hungryPeople;
    }
}
```

and then changing the Binding to `HungryPeople` instead. However, I don't find this a pretty option, as it involves making extra public properties, which may not be desirable. Is there a way to to all this within the XAML code?

Comment: You will want to implement a custom [collection view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx), if you want to sort and filter on demand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) with a filter:

The binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.MyGridView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:key="PeopleView" Source="{Binding People} Filter="ShowOnlyHungryPeople" />
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>    
         <DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PeopleView}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The filter:

```
private void ShowOnlyHungryPeople(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Person person = e.Item as Person;
    if (person != null)
    {
       e.Accepted = person.isHungry;
    }
    else e.Accepted = false;
}
```

Comment: That's a gorgeous solution, works! Unfortunately, the moment that the `DataContext` of `MyGridView` changes, the whole thing crashes. How can you bind the `Filter` to explicitly `MyGridView.ShowOnlyHungryPeople`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple properties, just create one `ObservableCollection` for your `Person` class and bind to `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid`.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Person> FilterPersons{get;set;}

 <DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterPersons}" />
```

initialize this collection with you `People` master list in the constructor of your View.

On every Filter (e.g, Hungary, Thirsty and so on) just add/remove `Person` from `FilterPersons` and your `DataGrid` will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do is use a Converter in your Binding, and there you can filter the List as you want , and return the filtered List.

```
<DataGrid Name="m_myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding People, Converter=myConverter}" />
```

And the Converter -

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<Person> hungryPeople = new List<Person>();
        foreach (Person person in value as List<Person>)
            if (person.isHungry)
                hungryPeople.Add(person);
        return hungryPeople;
    }
}
```